# select certain vertices and export the xyz coordinate

Tags: mesh, export, vertices, coordinates

How may I select certain vertices I want from this 3d mesh in Blender and export these vertices coordinates values as a table in a *.xls or *.csv file format?

I'm looking at 100 over vertices to be chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with this script:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

print ("started")



obj = bpy.context.active_object

verts = []

if bpy.context.mode == 'EDIT_MESH':
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    verts = [ v for v in bm.verts if v.select ]
else:
    verts = [ v for v in obj.data.vertices if v.select ]
    
    
for vertex in verts:
    print(vertex.co.x, ", ", vertex.co.y, ",",vertex.co.z)
```

[image]

result:

```
0.9238795042037964 ,  0.3826834261417389 , 1.0
0.7071067690849304 ,  -0.7071067690849304 , 1.0
```

Comment: I used this script successfully on a few objects.  I tried to use it on another object today, and the printed vertices are nonsense, i.e. they don't comport with the actual vertices in the object (looking manually within blender).  There's only one object in the scene.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please open a new question here…this is closed. Then I will take a look.